# Dealing with url request in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started learning codeigniter and i must say its pretty easy but I have a problem dealing with wrong urls, for example:

if I have an anchor tag like this 
    http://example.com/info/2
in the controller if I have

```
public function info( $x ) {
   $data['body'] = "Personal_info";
   $data['details'] = $this->person_model->get_detail( $x );
   $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
```

the controller grabs the links

```
segment (3)
```

and then grab the details of the id from the database.
 now for instance if a user manually edit the link on the browser and change the

```
segment(3)
```

to lets say 7 and there is no id in the database as 4.

how do I handle such a problem? I am a beginner so please pardon me

Comment: I have a 404 library page. If there is no result from database, I just load the 404 page and exit. It's up to you to decide what do you want to show to the user when the record was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `empty` method to check if there is data and if not redirect away from the page.

```
public function info( $x ) 
{
    $details = $this->person_model->get_detail( $x );
    if(empty($details))
        redirect('other/url');

    $data['body'] = "Personal_info";
    $data['details'] = details;
    $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
```

This way it doesn't throw errors and potentially attempt to display something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the passed `id` exists in database before trying to fetch related data, like:

```
$data_exists = $this->person_model->data_exists( $x );
if( $data_exists ) {
    $data['details'] = $this->person_model->get_detail( $x );
    $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
else {
   //load some view for showing no such id exists in db
}
```

where `data_exists()` can be a function in model which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on existance of your `id` in database.